# How do I disable Byobu?

Tags: byobu

When I try to disable Byobu on my Mac, all I get is

```
sed: -e: No such file or directory
```

What is this error?

I get the same message when I try to disable it from the menu.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem myself. I don't know what's happening to cause the `sed` error, but I was able to disable Byobu on login by opening `~/.zprofile` (I use zsh; try `~/.profile` if you use bash) and deleting a line that looked like

```
_byobu_sourced=1 . /opt/homebrew/Cellar/byobu/5.133_1/bin/byobu-launch 2>/dev/null || true
```